# CES in January 2012

Tags: discussion

I thought I would mention that CES, or the Consumer Electronics Show, for 2012 is occurring in Las Vegas from Jan. Tues 10 - Fri 13. CES is one of the biggest electronics shows in the world, and often a time when camera manufacturers unveil new gear.

I think it would be great if some of our membership could go this year, and report on all the new goodies. I suspect both Canon and Nikon will be revealing new consumer and prosumer grade bodies, Canon should be showing off some new lenses, and I suspect the other major manufacturers will have some new gear as well. One could speculate that the 1D X might be demoed.

If anyone is able to go to CES this coming year, let us know what you find out!